# Laravel 4 - best choice for PDF export library

Tags: php, pdf, laravel

I am using the DOMPDF library for PDF export in my Laravel 4 project. I have an array which can be exported to PDF. I am creating simple table to create the HTML:

```
$html = '<table>';
foreach ( $rows as $row ) {

   $html .= '
              <tr>
                <td>' .
                    $row->someInfo . 
               '</td>
              </tr>
            '
     }

   $html .= '</table>'

 PDF::load($html, 'A4', 'portrait')->download('filename');
```

But I have difficult struggle here with performance when I have more than 200 records in the array. It takes more than 30 seconds to render the PDF so I want to use another library. Which PDF export library is the best choice here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) is very fast. 
And install this wrapper [package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy) in Laravel to use the library.

I hope works for you.